# Changing from some CSS classes to others ones using jQuery .click with out toggling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the click of two buttons, I want to switch between two states, let's say *state a* and *state b*.

So I got two buttons:

`<button id="btnA">` and `<button id="btnB">`

I also got some `divs`: `bars`, `fx` and `table` with some initial classes given. Let's say some classes are for *state a* and some for *state b*.

So when I click `btnA` I want the divs to get **only** the classes meant for *state a* and so when click `btnB` make the divs get **only** the classes meant for *state b*.

The problem here is that I really don't want switching or toggling, whatever similarities have.

I tried this:

```
$("#btnA").click(function() {

    $(this).removeClass("btn-default")
    $(this).addClass("btn-success")

    $("#btnB").removeClass("btn-success")
    $("#btnB").addClass("btn-default")

    $("#table").remove()
    $("#bars").switchClass("barsdiferencias barslagrange")
    $("#fx").switchClass("fxdiferencias fxlagrange")
})

$("#btnB").click(function() {

    $(this).removeClass("btn-default")
    $(this).addClass("btn-success")

    $("#btnA").removeClass("btn-success")
    $("#btnA").addClass("btn-default")  


    $("#graficos").append('<div id="table" class="table"></div>')
    $("#bars").switchClass("barslagrange barsdiferencias")
    $("#fx").switchClass("fxlagrange fxdiferencias")        

})
```

I have tried using `switchClass` and `toggleClass` but they don't do what I want. I know removing the unwanted classes and adding the proper ones at each function would make it.
But, is there any fancier and shorter code solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow the question. Is it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/X6sn3/

Comment: have you considered just putting one single "state" class on a containing element of all of those elements, and styling them based on that one class?

Comment: I'm new to CSS, can I define something like that for multiple DOM elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

This just replaces the current class with the new one that you give in as parameter. The attr() method can be used to change any property of a tag.

```
    $(this).attr("class","btn-success")

    $("#btnA").attr("class","btn-default")
```

To add more classes

```
    $(this).attr("class","classA classB")
```

Comment: What when it comes to change between more than one?

Comment: you mean to add more classes?

Comment: Yes, exactly, for adding more than one class

Comment: to add more classes  .attr("class","classA classB") .. have ediited my answer too

Comment: So for one or more, it'll delete *all* applied classes and will add the given ones, right?

Comment: Yes it will just replace the class property

Comment: `.addClass()` <-- adds another class, `.removeClass()` <-- removes a specific class!